# how to print a canvas

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, pascal

I have a canvas which I draw to, to make slips for purchases made, I am trying to print the canvas out but am getting an error

'Project Project2.exe raised exception class EConvertError with message 'Cannot assign a TCanvasD2D to a TCanvasGdiPlus'

where am I going wrong?

```
var
printDialog : TPrintDialog;
myPrinter   : TPrinter;

begin



printDialog := TPrintDialog.Create(Form5);

if printDialog.Execute then
begin
  myPrinter := printer;
  with myPrinter do
  begin

    BeginDoc;

    Canvas.Assign(slipPnl.Canvas);

    EndDoc;
  end;
end;
end;
```

Comment: @Spektre thanks for the response, however I am a bit unsure what you mean, could you explain a bit more ?

Comment: I moved my comment into answer along with working (at lest for me) code

Comment: This is typically handled by separating your drawing code into its own function that takes a `TCanvas` as input, then you can draw to different kinds of canvases when needed. You don't copy one canvas to another.

Comment: I added [Edit1]  with alternative approach that should work even for Firemonkey ... in case my original approach does not work in it (I tested on VCL)

Answer (score 1):

The error suggest that probable causes is that source canvas is **DirectX** accelerated and printer is usually just **SW GDI** rendered which might prevent direct `Assign` due to Rendering Context incompatibility (the objects are too foreign to eachother).

Another possibility is that `Assign` also changes the resolution which I expect is not allowed for printer Canvas ...

Why not `CopyRect` and/or `StretchDraw` instead?

So copy the contents of source Canvas into printer Canvas or temp Canvas instead of Assign it directly...

OK here is VCL C++ example of what I mean (adapted from mine standard printing routine I use in my apps):

```cpp
void TMain::print(TCanvas *src,int xs,int ys)
    {
    // just check if any printers available first
    TPrinter *prn = Printer();
    int pxs,pys,psz,i=0;
    if (prn==NULL) i=1;
    if (prn->Printers==NULL) i=1;
    if (prn->Printers->Count<=0) i=1;
    if (i) return;

    // used print dialog component
    TPrintDialog *dlg_print=PrintDialog1;
    dlg_print->Options.Clear();
    dlg_print->Options<<poPrintToFile;
    if (!dlg_print->Execute()) return;

    // printer settings
    prn = Printer();
    pxs=prn->PageWidth;
    pys=prn->PageHeight;

    // create printer page backbuffer
    Graphics::TBitmap *bmp=new Graphics::TBitmap;
    bmp->HandleType=bmDIB;
    bmp->PixelFormat=pf32bit;
    bmp->SetSize(pxs,pys);

    // compute scale
    float zoom,xx,yy;
    xx=pxs/xs;
    yy=pys/ys;
    zoom=xx; if (zoom>yy) zoom=yy;
    xx=xs; xx*=zoom;
    yy=ys; yy*=zoom;

    // copy Incompatible canvas into GDI Canvas (bmp)
    bmp->Canvas->CopyRect
        (
        TRect(0,0,xx,yy),
        src,
        TRect(0,0,xs,ys)
        );

    // bmp->SaveToFile("print.bmp"); // just for debug so I do not need actually print

    prn->BeginDoc();
    for (i=0;i<dlg_print->Copies;i++)
        {
        if (i) prn->NewPage();
        // render GDI Canvas (bmp) to printer page
        prn->Canvas->Draw(0,0,bmp);
        }
    prn->EndDoc();

    // release stuff
    delete bmp;
    }
```

using BDS2006 Turbo C++ (direct successor to BCB6 and Delphi)... just convert the C++ syntax to Pascal the rest should be the same... The Idea is to use temp bitmap (you might also directly render to printer page instead) and `CopyRect` instead of Assign ... However you **need to pass resolution of the `TCanvas`** as that is not accessible directly (as its usually a property of parent object).

**[Edit1]**

As Marco van de Voort pointed out you are using Firemonkey which I have no experience with and missed it while answering so in case the above code is not working you can workaround with different approach ...

Simply copy the `Canvas` content using **Winapi** see:

- [How can I access a graphics card's output directly?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38549548/2521214)

and look for bullet **#2** with name **WinAPI approach** in order to make it work you need `Handle` of the `Canvas` which should be a accessible property  of the `Canvas` or its parent object. If it is not you can still do this see:

- [How to find the active child form of MDI parent from User control which is loaded in MDI Parent at runtime in C#.net?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21330590/2521214)
- [is ther a way an app can display a message without the use of messagebox API?](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/a/11920/4709)

On how to obtain the `Handle` using **Winapi** again.

Comment: Note his firemonkey tag.

Comment: @MarcovandeVoort hmm didn't see that however looks like the class names and function order is the same anyway (but I have no experience with firemonkey are there any diferences?)

Comment: Firemonkey is owner drawn and doesn't use GDI primitives. So printing can't assume a GDI canvas (as you can see from the error, it is a direct2d canvas), though there might ways around that for the initiated. I don't use FM, I only know the principles.

Comment: @MarcovandeVoort I added [Edit1]  with alternative approach that should work even for Firemonkey ...